# How to implement a 2D graph with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I am working on developing something in it and I am confused about how to draw/construct a two-dimensional discrete graph (prototype attached below) in react native. Can anyone suggest anything how this can be achieved by any means? Thank you.

Note: I also need to join the four fields for e.g. Low-Tech, Derivative, Regular, Assembly  (through a line or something? This can be done through PolyLine component I suppose). Joining of four fields will form a 'diamond' hence the name.

[image]

Comment: hie! can you share what you have tried so far! you should try mixing.  D3.js and react-native-svg for such chart!

Comment: though D3 and svg will be too much to handle for such simple chart! you have like veritcal view and center view dividers and simply just put view based item groups and rotate them if you want it simple like in the pic

Comment: react-native-chart-kit is a good charting library. Will also echo recommendation to use d3.js and react-native-svg. With that approach, I recommend building simple code examples on the web first and then convert to React Native.